# JDBC SELECT very slow in comparison to Firefox DB manager

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

**Solved**, of course after posting here it hit me... Now using different drivers from http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC#Download that don't need extensive configuration.

Original question below the break.

---

I'm fooling around with a SQLite database containing OpenStreetMap data, and I'm having some trouble with JDBC.

The query below is the one I'd like to use to get a location close to the location of my user quicky (numbers are from my test-data, and are added by the java code).

```
SELECT roads.nodeID, lat, lon 
FROM roads 
INNER JOIN nodes 
ON roads.nodeID=nodes.nodeID 
ORDER BY (ABS(lat - (12.598418)) + ABS(lon - (-70.043514))) ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

'roads' and 'nodes' both contain approximately 130,000 rows.

This specific query is one of the most intensive buyt it's only used twice so that should be OK for my needs. It executes in about 281 ms when using the Firefox SQLite, but in Java using sqlitejdbc-v056 it takes between 12 and 14 seconds (with full processor load).

Any clues on how to fix this?

```
public Node getNodeClosestToLocation(Location loc){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            String q = "SELECT roads.nodeID, lat, lon "+
            "FROM roads "+
            "INNER JOIN nodes "+
            "ON roads.nodeID=nodes.nodeID "+
            "ORDER BY (ABS(lat - ("+loc.getLat()+")) +
            ABS(lon - ("+loc.getLon()+"))) ASC "+
            "LIMIT 1";
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(q);

            rs = stat.executeQuery(q);
            if(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Done. " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));

                return new Node(rs.getInt("nodeID"), rs.getFloat("lat"), rs.getFloat("lon"));
            }   

        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How come sqllite query is related to browser? Could that some other component in application?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: that was just to demonstrate that the query itself should not be slow per-se as another appliction (the SQLite DB Manager plugin for the Firefox browser in this case) does it a lot faster. You can see me doing the timing, and it's a very 'young' project with just one single thread running.

Comment: are you sure you use the same amount of data, the same query and the results are the same? and both are read from the same memory storage - RAM / HDD / SDD? if you read 100 rows from RAM for FF test and 130 000 from HDD for Java, there would be no wonder :) otherwise,, it is probably a bug in Java's implementation

Comment: Just for the sake of comparison please try:


SELECT (ABS(lat - (12.598418)) + ABS(lon - (-70.043514))) as distance, roads.nodeID, lat, lon 
FROM roads 
INNER JOIN nodes 
ON roads.nodeID=nodes.nodeID 
ORDER BY 1 ASC 
LIMIT 1

Comment: Also if you have the same query executed twice in a row the second execution will be faster because the server cached the data

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to select statement queries in JDBC, they can be very painfully slow if they're not utilized correctly. A few points:

1. Make sure you index the proper columns in your table.  A simple line such as:

`Statement stat = connection.createStatement();

stat.executeUpdate("create index {index_name} on orders({column_name});");

   stat.close();`

Creating an index: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

1. Insertion takes longer with indices, since each previous index needs to be updated as new records are inserted. Creating an index is best done after all the insert statements have been executed (better performance). Indexed columns take a hit on insertion performance but have significantly faster selection performance.
2. Changing the JDBC driver may help slightly but overall should not be the underlying issue. Also make sure you're running in native mode. Pure-java mode is significantly slower, at least from what I've noticed. The following code segment will tell you which mode you're running, assuming you're using SQLite JDBC.

`System.out.println(String.format("%s mode", SQLiteJDBCLoader.isNativeMode() ? "native" : "pure-java"));`

I experienced the same issue with slow selections in a database with more than 500K records. The run time of my application would have been 9.9 days if I had not indexed. Now it is a blazing fast 2 minutes to do the exact same thing. SQLite is very fast when proper and optimized sql is used.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) might give you slightly better performances but nothing of the magnitude described here.

Perhaps Firefox SQLite is using some hints. You could try to get the execution plan to see where the query is doing the hard work and create some index if required.

Have you tried to log any timing information to make sure it is not getting the connection which is expensive?